# BeautifulSoup: Empty entries? not working anymore?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to convert a xml (google contacts) into a csv using BeautifulSoup. I have a script that worked perfectly, but it stopped working now without making any changes to the source. Maybe BeautifulSoup changed??

So, the xml file has entries like:

```
 <entry ns1:etag="&quot;RcDVSLt7I2AQEQAM.&quot;">
 <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/..." />
 <title>Pepe Estropajo</title>
 </edited>
 <name>
 <fullName>Pepe</fullName>
 <givenName>...</givenName>
 <familyName>Estropajo</familyName>
 </name>
 </entry>
```

and I want to extract the data. So I did:

```
 for entry in soup.findAll('entry'):
 name = entry.title
 ....
```

Problem is that **name** is **None**. Why it doesn't find **title**?
I asked for the script  to print **name**, and it printed:

```
<entry ns1:etag='"Rng-cDVSLyt7I2A9Wh5QEEUNQAM."'></entry>
```

without any child inside.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you parsing the XML? `BeautifulSoup(source, 'xml')` or otherwise?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: like this: agxml="/home/gato/varios/google-contacts.xml" soup = BeautifulSoup(open(agxml,'r').read(), fromEncoding="Latin1")

Comment: Then you are opening the file *as HTML*, and not XML. Different parsing rules apply in that case. Do you have `lxml` installed? Is this BeautifulSoup 3 or 4?

Comment: Not sure, I've both installed: python-BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-7 and
python-beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-1. I call it with from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I tried with soup = BeautifulSoup(open(agxml,'r').read(), 'xml') and soup = BeautifulSoup(open(agxml,'r').read(), 'xml', fromEncoding="Latin1") and get lots of errors...

Comment: Your code works fine for me. i am using `beautifulsoup4`. I used `from bs4 import Beautifulsoup`

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: then you are using BeautifulSoup *3*. Use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Yes, switched to bs4 and now it works (I just added 'xml'). So it seems that bs3 stopped working properly... Maybe you want to post this as an answer? Anyway, thanks to both of you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
>>> entries = """<entry ns1:etag="&quot;RcDVSLt7I2AQEQAM.&quot;">
...  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/..." />
...  <title>Pepe Estropajo</title>
...  </edited>
...  <name>
...  <fullName>Pepe</fullName>
...  <givenName>...</givenName>
...  <familyName>Estropajo</familyName>
...  </name>
...  </entry>"""
>>> 
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(entries)
>>> 
>>> for entry in soup.findAll('entry'):
...     print entry.find('title').getText()
... 
Pepe Estropajo
```

Comment: Probably. I read contents from a file. The question was already answered by Martin and salman above: there is indeed a problem with BS3, and BS4 works fine. Thanks anyway!!